# Changing sort criteria in search doesn't change header

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

If I…

1. Click a question (i.e. a hot question) in the feed
2. Click a tag in that question to perform a tag search
3. Change the sort criteria

…the header update as expected. In the example below, the results are actually sorted by votes, not relevance:

[image: search results with incorrect header]

I've only found this to be reproducible when getting to the search results via the specific method above; in all other cases I've tried the header seems to update appropriately.

Comment: I've had this happen a few other ways now, but not in a way I could intentionally reproduce.

Comment: Taking a look.  Should have something to say about it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened here is that there are actually two table views laying on top of each other when search is being used - search results on top of the question listing.  Normally, when search becomes active the question list section header height and title are set to `nil` and `0`, respectively, and the search results just lay on top.

In this case when we navigated directly to a search, we weren't setting these values properly, and so what you're seeing is actually the section header for the question listing. When you change the sort for your search results, it does change the header, but it's underneath the other header, which is incorrect.

For fun, and to see the effect, you can pull the search results down like you would do for a pull-to-refresh, and you'll see the other header emerge :-)

[image]

This will be fixed in the next build, which will be available tonight.